# Does grails internationalization work in index.gsp?

Tags: grails, internationalization

If we type the following, the language of the web application changes properly:

```
http://localhost:8080/yourCoolWebApp/behappy/list?lang=en
http://localhost:8080/yourCoolWebApp/smile/list?lang=es
```

But if we type an uri that doesn't have a controller, the language shown is the default one. This is the case of index.gsp. If we type the following code, the shown language is the default one always:

```
http://localhost:8080/?lang=en
http://localhost:8080/?lang=es
```

[In this old bug report](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3871), marked as won't fix, there is a solution. I tried to implement it. I changed the following line of my `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
"/"(view:"/index")
```

by:

```
"/"(view:"/index", controller:"foo")
```

But, after a *grails clean*, `index.gsp` keep being in the default language always.

I also have another view without a controller, so I also had the following line of code in `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
name contact: "/contact"(view:"contact")
```

I changed it by:

```
name contact: "/contact"(view:"contact", controller:"foo")
```

I got a: `The requested resource is not available` *(/webAlojamientoUCA/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/foo/contacto.jsp)*

I'm using Grails 2.2.4.

Comment: Do you have the action "contact" defined in "foo"? The gsp exists? The i18n needs to pass though the controller layer, so you're in the right path creating the action.

Comment: @SérgioMichels: gsp exists, controller doesn't (that's why I have it defined in `UrlMappings`). So, in this case, we could just create a _controller contact_ with just one empty _action contact_. What do you usually do with the index.gsp. Do you also have a controller for it?

Comment: In my experience the "...?lang=en" doesn't work...not much help but I gave up.

Comment: @chelder Yes, you need to create the controller.

Comment: @marko I use the lang attribute and it works, but only if you have a controller.

Comment: @marko, maybe it is related to grails doesn't have the following file:  `messages_en.properties`. By default, Grails doesn't have this file as the default language (´messages.properties´) is English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grails' i18n infrastructure relies on the logic passing through the controller layer](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3355)

Yes you need to create/have controller !

Something like

UrlMappings

```
"/"(controller: 'index')
```

and controller

```
class IndexController {

    def index() {
    }
}
```

and view ${appName}/grails-app/views/index/index.gsp

Comment: This is exactly what has been mentioned in the bug you mentioned @chelder

Comment: I guess you're right @dmahapatro. Maybe I got confused because naming the controller as "foo". Anyway, I think it is actually more clear for everybody who looks for the same question now.